# Member of array is undefined, has all the data to get the member

Tags: javascript

I have an array of elemens, it is populated but all the members are `undefined`.

```
// Result: [div.some-class, div.some-class, div.some-class, div.some-class]
console.log(myArray);

// Result: 4
console.log(myArray.length);

for(var i = 0 ; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {

        console.log(myArray[i]); // <- This is "undefined"
        console.log(myArray);    // <- Successful log: has access to array
        console.log(i);          // <- Successful log: has access to "i"

        // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
        myArray[i].classList.add('yeah');  

    }, i * 200);
}
```

---

It works without timeout:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    // No errors -> it works
    myArray[i].classList.add('yeah');  
}
```

`myArray` is a global value and timeout has access to every data it needs. **Why it's still undefined?**

Comment: The value of variable `i` is past the last element when those functions actually run. Your `for` loop completes before they get to run! As you should have seen the value of `i` always is 4 in your output, which is the value after loop completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the timeout invokes the function, the loop has already ended, which means the `i` is equal to 4.

Here's an easy fix:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function(i) {

            myArray[i].classList.add('yeah');  

        }, i * 200)
    })(i);
}
```

You simply invoke the timeout with each `i` and pass that `i` to the function

Comment: There's a `)` missing somewhere and I cannot figure out the right place.. :-D

Comment: yup. added the missing `)`

Comment: Already tried it before, still get the error in `)(i);` area. Error: `setTimeout(...) is not a function`

Comment: wrap it in a function

Comment: The easiest solution is to change `var` to `let`.

Comment: @torazaburo it doesn't look like he's writing ES6 code...